# why i cant access mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I have been dealing with this issue for a while.
I think that everything is right but it keeps telling that there is a problem with the query, which actually the case. But I can't really find it.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
function query_check ($query)
{
    if(!$query)
    {
        die ("Database query failed");

    }
}

function Create($Name,$Last_Name,$Number)
{ 
global $conncetion;

$S_Name=mysqli_real_escape_string($conncetion,$Name);
$S_Last_Name=mysqli_real_escape_string($conncetion,$Last_Name);
$S_Number=mysqli_real_escape_string($conncetion,$Number);
$query="INSERT INTO phone_book.info (first_name,last_name,phone_number)
VALUES ({$S_Name},{$S_Last_Name},{$S_Number}); ";
$result=mysqli_query($conncetion,$query);
query_check($result);   
}

//Delete
function Del($Name,$Last_Name,$Number)
{   
    global $conncetion;

    $S_Name=mysqli_real_escape_string($conncetion,$Name);
    $S_Last_Name=mysqli_real_escape_string($conncetion,$Last_Name);
    $S_Number=mysqli_real_escape_string($conncetion,$Number);
    $query="DELETE FROM ";
    $query.="phone_book.info WHERE first_name={$S_Name} OR last_name={$S_Last_Name} OR phone_number={$S_Number}";
    $result=mysqli_query($conncetion,$query);
    query_check($result);

}

function Search($Name,$Last_Name,$Number)
{
    global $conncetion;

    $S_Name=mysqli_real_escape_string($conncetion,$Name);
    $S_Last_Name=mysqli_real_escape_string($conncetion,$Last_Name);
    $S_Number=mysqli_real_escape_string($conncetion,$Number);
    $query="select * from info where first_name={$S_Name} or last_name={$S_Last_Name} or phone_number={$S_Number}";
    $result=mysqli_query($conncetion, $query);
    query_check($result);
    if($search=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
             return $search["first_name"];
             return $search["last_name"];
             return $search["phone_number"];
    } else
    {
        return "No such information was found";
    }

}
?>
```

I hope that you can help me find the problem.

Comment: Nothing is being executed here. Why use so many separate `<?php` tags? Funny. It's probably your connection. Look at `new mysqli()` or `mysqli_connect()`.

Comment: Can you post the section of code where you are running into issues? Also the observed results and the expected results. Please refer to this on posting questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you check if you have posted the complete code? These are just functions and none of them are being called..

Comment: @ShuchiSethi @Adam it is just a simple CRUD application and the other parts are just some HTML forms and mysql connection...this is the main part...so i just didn`t post the other parts...

Comment: @PHPglue Tnx for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your Sql you are inserting what I'm assuming are many string values however not one of them is quoted so Sql will be trying to insert them as integers.

This for example:

```
$query="INSERT INTO phone_book.info (first_name,last_name,phone_number) VALUES ({$S_Name},{$S_Last_Name},{$S_Number}); ";
```

Should be as follows:

```
$query="INSERT INTO phone_book.info (first_name,last_name,phone_number) VALUES ('{$S_Name}','{$S_Last_Name}','{$S_Number}'); ";
```

You have exactly the same issue with your delete and select statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="INSERT INTO phone_book.info (first_name,last_name,phone_number) VALUES ('$S_Name','$S_Last_Name','$S_Number')";
```